# How do I use shell commands with a directory that contains '-' like '-78059735'?

Tags: bash, shell, escape-characters

I have an external program that generates directories with strings that are negative integers. I am trying to use basic shell commands including `cd` and `ls` with this directory, for example:

`cd -78059735`

Understandably, this fails because this looks like command line options starting with -7.

> -bash: cd: -7: invalid option

Similarly, these variations also fail:

```
cd "-78059735"
cd "\-78059735"
cd '-78059735'
cd '\-78059735'
cd \-78059735
```

How do I interact with this troublesome directory through the shell?

Answer (score 5):

It is because the command `cd` treats the character followed by `-` as valid option flag for it to work. Since `7` is not a valid one for `cd` it is failing with the error you are seeing.

In such cases you can specify end of command line options by doing a double dash before the command name `--` as below. The below command implies that the command line options for `cd` are complete and there are *no* other flags expected after `--`

```
cd -- -78059735/
```

You can even have other flags provided before `--` which would work just fine. The below command for `mkdir` which takes an option `-p` to create a directory if it does not exist before works just fine with a string having `-`, provided you give an end of command line options flag right after `-p`

```
mkdir -p -- /tmp/-78059735
ls -d /tmp/*
/tmp/-78059735
```

`rm` command to delete a directory also works just fine as below

```
rm -vrf -- /tmp/-78059735
removed directory '/tmp/-78059735'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cd ./-78059735
ls ./-78059735
```

It works for me.